# D3 bar chart with variable width and variable length data up to 1000 data points

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am having a lot of trouble with D3 bar chart where the length of the data I get from search is variable.  I used the D3 bar chart example and built this.  However as data length goes up, the graph gets less and less legible.  The problem seems to be the range gets confused when it is beyond 100 points or so.

Code is below:

```
function makegraph(data,ctype) {
//var data=xdata.splice(-900)
var gwidth=data.length*2;
if(gwidth < 800) gwidth=800;
//gwidth=800
var margin = {top: 9, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 90},
    width = gwidth - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

 x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
//x=d3.scale.linear().domain([0,1]).range(0,width)

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(function(d) { if (d % 10) return ""; else return d;})

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");
//    .ticks(10, "%");

d3.select("svg").remove()
var svg = d3.select("#graphchart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.rowid); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d[ctype]); });

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.rowid; }));
  var ymax=d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[ctype]; });
  var ymin=d3.min(data, function(d) { return d[ctype]; });
  y.domain([ymin, ymax]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);


svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", Math.log10(ymax))
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Bytes");
// console.log(x.rangeBand())

  var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data);
    bar.enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.rowid); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[ctype]); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { var xya= height - y(d[ctype]); /* console.log(xya+":"+d[ctype]); */ return height - y(d[ctype]); })
      /* .attr("title", function(d) { return d['bytes']+" Bytes at "+d.stime; }) */
      .on("mouseover", function(d) { $("#graphinfo").html(d3.format('0,000')(d['bytes'])+" Bytes at "+d.stime) })
      .on("mouseout",function(d) { $("#graphinfo").html('&nbsp;')})
      .on("click",function(d) { tablegraph(d)});
$('.bar').tooltip()

}
```

Do you have suggestions how I can make this graph so that the bar chart will grow horizontally for larger data sets?  Thanks for any help and suggestions!

Vijay

Comment: What do you mean by grow?  You want a large horizontally scroll?  Just set your `gwidth` to some large value...